# How to trace sql query in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, go

```
sql.Register("sqlWithHooks", sqlhooks.Wrap(r.Driver(), &Hooks{}))

// Connect to the registered wrapped driver
db, err := sql.Open("sqlWithHooks", ":memory:")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("error",err)

}

rows, err := db.Query("SELECT id,name,cid,dimension,price FROM   table_name ")

if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("inside the error .........................",err)

}
```

After running this code I am getting an error missing "=" after ":memory:" in connection info string. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with what I've done here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sql.Open() expects 2 things 'driverName' and 'dataSourceName'. In case of [sqlhooks](https://github.com/gchaincl/sqlhooks) example, they used sqlite as database. Apart from that, they have used [go-sqlite3](https://github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3) and if you look closely to file [sqlite3.go](https://github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3/blob/1fc3fd346d3cc4c610f432d8bc938bb952733873/sqlite3.go) at line number 886. You would see datasourcename ':memory:' that means we are opting for in-memory utilization of sqlite db.

'dataSourceName' will vary as per the database opted. Its basically means connection string in Data Source Name format.

Reason why this worked
fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%d user=%s password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable",
            host, port, user, password, dbname)

Answer (score 4):

The second argument of `sql.Open()` expects a connection string. It has the following form:

```
fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%d user=%s password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable",
            host, port, user, password, dbname)
```

It contains the needed information to open a connection to Postgres.